# can a Java Interface change even though the client project won't be compiled again?

Tags: java

I am trying to change an interface in Proj2. 
However, Proj1 is already using this interface, and won't be compiled with my new version.

Looks like problems occur only if I change/delete existing methods but adding new methods seems to be not causing any issues.

So as long as I only "add" methods to the interface, I can expect Proj1 to be fine with the latest Jar of Proj2.

Is that a rock solid safe assumption?

Update: 
Both the interface and impl reside in proj2.  Proj1 has no implementation of that that interface.

Comment: Following your update `Proj1 is already using this interface` vs `Proj1 has no implementation of that that interface`. How ?

Comment: You first state that `Proj1 is already using this interface`.  Then you add a comment that says `Proj1 has no implementation of that interface.`  How can both statements be true?

Comment: Proj1 is invoking a method on the interface.

Comment: to be clear:  Proj2 creates the Impl, and feeds it to Proj1.  Its regular polymorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By "using," you mean "references an object using the interface and invokes interface-defined methods using that reference," not "implements the interface" (yes, you've clarified in comments, but I just want to repeat, because all the other answers are about implementing the interface).

In that case, as long as you have not removed methods from the interface or change their signature, your existing code will work.

The reason that this will work is that the compiler translates the method calls into an [invokeinterface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-6.html#jvms-6.5.invokeinterface) bytecode, which references the interface class and method by name. At *runtime*, the JVM simply validates that the actual reference implements the interface, and invokes the method.

If you *remove* or *change* a referenced interface method, one of two things will happen: either the JVM will refuse to load the class in proj1, because the interface reference could not be resolved, or it will give a `NoSuchMethodError` (I believe it's the second). Same thing if you remove or change a referenced method in a concrete class.

Answer (score 3):

No. Adding new methods to the interface or updating its current signature would require you to provide the implementation of those methods in classes where you have implemented the interface.

However, when you remove a particular method declaration from an interface, *even though it is defined in the class implementing the interface*, there would be no effect. The removed method would just serve to be a normal method of the class, no longer tied with the existing contract of the interface.

The only way that I can think of solving your issue is to take the advantage of Java letting you implement multiple interfaces for a given class. What you should try to do is create a new interface, define your new methods over here and let your classes in proj2 implement this interface as well. This way, when you package your new jar, your existing classes in proj1 would remain unaffected.

Comment: both the interface and impl reside in proj2. I will update my post.

Comment: If Project1 won't be recompiled, then it means any class using this interface won't use the new methods.

Comment: @rk2010: If your proj1 does not have any class that *implements* the interface from proj2, they'll remain unaffected with the addition of the new jar. However, this will not be the case if classes in proj1 implements this interface.

Comment: I can take care of Proj2 because I am compiling it. I am just not 100% sure that Proj1 will be OK.

Comment: @rk2010: I updated my answer with one possible solution for your problem

Comment: @Sujay While I like that approach, I am really interested in knowing  whether the original approach is a 100% safe assumption.

Comment: @rk2010: Judging by your new edit and the assumption that there're no classes in proj1 that implements the interface defined in proj2, yes - your assumption is correct :)

Comment: @downvoter: can you please explain the reasoning behind down-voting this? I would love to edit/update my answer, provided I know what I wrong :) It doesn't help me nor the OP if you **don't** comment on why you think the down-vote was necessary!

Answer (score 2):

If you're just adding methods, create a second interface.  Java classes can implement more than one interface.  That way, the classes that implement Interface1 remain the same.

Your newer class(es) implement interfaces Interface1 and Interface2.

Comment: Sure. but my Q is about something different. I wanna know what is 100% OK

Comment: Creating a second interface is 100% ok.

Answer (score 0):

you will get the error:

```
The type XXXImpl must implement the inherited abstract method IXXX.method()
```

Comment: By OP question, there aren't classes on Proj1 that implements the interface in Proj2. This error won't raise.

Comment: There is only one Impl. and that lives in Proj2. and yes, I will be implementing the new method in the Impl.

Comment: Impl is created by another utility in Proj2, and then its provided to Proj1. Regular polymorphism